# WebGL disabled or unavailable on Chrome / MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, webgl

I'm on macOS 10.13.6 on a Mac mini. I'm seeing the following behavior on Google Chome 68.0.3440.106 and Chrome Canary 70.0.3529.3.

I go to https://get.webgl.org/ and I see the message:

> Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card.

Firefox and Safari both render the WebGL scene here just fine. Can anyone tell me how to enable WebGL on Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: https://wevideo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/225259448-How-to-enable-WebGL and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141974/does-webgl-work-on-chrome-on-a-mac may be useful... but if it's gpu blacklisted dunno...there may be a reason for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to start Chrome with `--ignore-gpu-blacklist`, or just use Firefox. See: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/co6w-9D1ZWo/-ZMOftQ3DAAJ

Here's the change that breaks this in Chromium: https://codereview.chromium.org/2076443002/

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac has an Intel HD 3000 GPU (my mac mini mid 2011 does), then it won't work as it's been blacklisted: https://codereview.chromium.org/2076443002/